# Open pdf files located inside the App (raw folder)

Tags: android, file, pdf

I need to open in an external app (like Adobe Reader) some pdf files located inside the app (raw folder)

I try to use this code that work perfect if the files are in the SD card but, if i try to put the app (package) directory in the file line, nothing happens:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File("/sdcard/myfile2.pdf");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(referencias.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Also i try this code.
The app Adobe reader open but i receive an invalid access directory error:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                 i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///data/app/mypackage/res/raw/myfile.pdf"),
            "application/pdf");

            try{
                startActivity(i);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(referencias.this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Last solution is to copy the pdf file every time from the raw folder to the SD card, like [this tutorial](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/writeSD.html).

But is really complicated and a lot of code.

Comment: "file:///data/app/mypackage/res/raw/myfile.pdf" is not a valid URL, as there are no literal file-system files within the package. If it's possible to access the contents of an .apk via a URL, it would have to be one of a different form - all file:///data/app/... can get you is the zip file that is the .apk itself.

Comment: would you be so kind as to show me onSave code, I think that the problem is with File file =new File(...);

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the pdf using the app, the apps file permissions might not allow external visibility.  Check out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: The question specifies the raw folder, which is not writable by the application, so the PDF must have been pre-packaged making this answer inapplicable.

Comment: Thanks to all. I check the link above and i find this tip: "If you want to save a static file in your application at compile time, save the file in your project res/raw/ directory. You can open it with openRawResource(), passing the R.raw.<filename> resource ID. This method returns an InputStream that you can use to read the file (but you cannot write to the original file)." Somebody can help me with a sample code?

Comment: Yea, you would save the file in /res/raw, and then use an input stream to read bytes from the file: InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.my_file );

But I think you what you really want to bundle a pdf file with your app, and then use the app to view it.  It way to get that to work is by using the sd card.  I think that this question would be more use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder

Answer (score 0):

try this things:

```
File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "your_file.ext"); // ext meens extension .doc .zip ....
```

then save your data to this file, make an intent, that you'v made... but 
use the mFile instead of creating new file or

```
File fileForUri=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"your_file.ext"
```

try this