# Reading a pdf file placed in assets folder in android

Tags: android, path, uri, assets

I have a pdf file placed in my assets folder and I am firing an intent to read it.
Here is my code :

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android:asset/about.pdf");
   Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
```

When I do this, apop up appears with list of applications including adobe reader
but when I click on it, a dialog appears saying :"Error", the file path is not valid

Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/how-to-read-a-pdf-in-android

Comment: I tried this - File file = new File("file:///android:asset/about.pdf");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this file in your app's assets folder? If it is, then your URI is wrong, check out this question:

[How to open a pdf stored either in res/raw or assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder)

there's an answer describing how to construct a proper URIs for your assets.