# Open and display pdf-file stored locally

Tags: android, pdf, local-storage, file-management

After reading through several Q/A, I still can't find a suitable answer for my current issue.

I have a pdf-file (known at compile time) which is stored in my /res/raw folder.

I have tried loading the file using:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mypdf);
```

Then I want to display the pdf (in an intent) using the preferred pdf-reader on the device:

```
Intent i;
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(file,"application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

The issue is that the intent takes in the type 'File', while my pdf is read as an 'InputStream'.

The question is: How can i display the pdf-file? i.e. how can I display an InputStream? or how can I store the pdf-file to allow opening with new File()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display PDF within app on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this..
    //place pdf in asset folder just to try

```
Uri file= Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/mypdf.pdf");
  String mimeType =  MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.toString()));

try{
     Intent i;
     i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setDataAndType(file,mimeType);
     startActivity(i);

}catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, 
                        "No Application Available to fiew this file type", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: It throws an ActivityNotFoundException. Furthermore the String mimeType is blank (using Toast). It seems like the extension isn't recognized.

Comment: Okay... Problem is there is no application in your device to read a pdf file.. Install adobe reader and try again...

Comment: did you try to display mimetype?

Comment: I have adobe reader, but the actual string returned in mimeType (2nd line in your code) is blank, so the intent is called as i.setDataAndType(file,""). But is this an issue with the file/storage method or the MimeTypeMap function on a resource?

Comment: getMimeTypeFromExtension(".pdf")

Comment: hey i edited the code can you just place that file in asset folder and try my code? because its not taking a proper mimetype. is that your requirment to place it in raw folder?

Comment: It now seems like it attempts to open the pdf-reader, but the app 'force quit' before anything is displayed. I'm concerned that the file is not recognized as .pdf when it is accessed using Uri.parse().

Comment: In now prompt me to choose between Adobe/QuickOffice, but gives the error: "The document path is not valid." (It does NOT throw the ActivityNotFoundException)

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder

Comment: I ended up putting the files online, and then downloading it to external storage before viewing. Thanks for you help anyways!

Comment: Try saving the pdf file using the InputStream 'is' to the external storage and then create a Uri to that file like:
 file = new File("pathtofile");
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);

Answer (score 1):

*you could use an extern library [joanzapata.pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)*

this code will show your pdf whereever u want in your layout

```
 

    private PDFView pdfview;
    pdfview = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
    File file = new File(filepath);
    pdfview.fromFile(file)
                    .defaultPage(1)
                    .showMinimap(false)
                    .enableSwipe(true)
                    .onLoad(this)
                    .onPageChange(this)
                    .load();
```

*or if the file is known at compile time and u have the pdf in the asset folder:*

```
 

    private PDFView pdfview;
    pdfview = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
    pdfview.fromAsset(pdfName)
                    .defaultPage(1)
                    .showMinimap(false)
                    .enableSwipe(true)
                    .onLoad(this)
                    .onPageChange(this)
                    .load();
```

*add this in your layout*

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
                android:id="@+id/pdfview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```