# Read a pdf file from assets folder

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, android-assets

```
public void DOCS(View btnDocs)
{   
    File fileBrochure = new File("android.resource://com.project.datastructure/assets/abc.pdf");
    if (!fileBrochure.exists())
    {
         CopyAssetsbrochure();
    } 

    /** PDF reader code */
    File file = new File("android.resource://com.project.datastructure/assets/abc.pdf");        

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try 
    {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
    {
         Toast.makeText(Stack_dr.this, "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private void CopyAssetsbrochure() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try 
    {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } 
    catch (IOException e){}
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        String fStr = files[i];
        if(fStr.equalsIgnoreCase("abc.pdf"))
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try 
            {
              in = assetManager.open(files[i]);
              out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + files[i]);
              copyFile(in, out);
              in.close();
              in = null;
              out.flush();
              out.close();
              out = null;
              break;
            } 
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}

 private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException 
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a pdf file from assets folder which is present in my application folder . Everything is working perfectly when i click on my DOCS button a pop up comes to let me choose an application for opening the pdf i.e "abc.pdf" but after selecting an option i get an error message "The file path is not valid". I think their is some problem with the path which i have specified in the code.
please help

Comment: have You checked if the copied pdf really exists on your sd card? By the way, You should specify with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to specify the path instead of "/sdcard/"

Comment: The pdf exists in my assets folder which will b shipped along with the app

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            CopyReadAssets();

        }

        private void CopyReadAssets()
        {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "abc.pdf");
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("abc.pdf");
                out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/abc.pdf"),
                    "application/pdf");

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

    }
```

Make sure to include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in manifest

Comment: So we have to must write in external storage? without copy is it possible to open directly?

Comment: @sunil hi I am trying the same code but getting error Activity not found.COuld you help me why is it happening

Comment: @poojagupta Actvity not found that you have not mentioned in the Menifest file, Check manifest file

Comment: @sunil I have mentioned it but still getting error for the Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/abc.pdf"),
                    "application/pdf");

            startActivity(intent);

Comment: Sunil, I have tried the same code but its saying file not found, though

Comment: Might be you Not putted file in assets folder

Comment: Does this still work, after Google's latest tightening up of security on sdcards?

Comment: Kindly tell me why its not working on Android 7.1 Nought ?

Comment: kindly anyone here to help me i try above code but it shows me file no longer exists.

Comment: The above does not work with Android 7 or greater, can you please update the answer for android 7 or greater?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647784/trying-to-open-pdf-file-from-assets-folder-using-fileprovider-but-it-gives-filen?answertab=active#tab-top "this will help you")!
one

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this (tested and working on API 27)

**Step 1**

Add following dependency in your app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

**Step 2**

Add following XML code:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
         android:id="@+id/pdfv"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>
```

**Step 3**

Add following code in your java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PDFView pdfView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfv);
        pdfView.fromAsset("filename.pdf").load();
    }
}
```

These changes will load a PDF file on creation of your activity.

Comment: @ViddyutKhanvilkar it just didn't load anything, but would be some mistake of mine. I'm using another approach for pdf now

Comment: @Felipe Santiago. What approach did you take?

Comment: Can I use this approach for an online pdf in the server?

Comment: @DavidKariuki if I remeber, i did something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578661/4407308

Comment: Thank you! Felipe.

Comment: barteksc library taking so much space in apk.

Answer (score 6):

Though this has been answered, I wanted to share my solution as I think it is a bit easier to include.

Usage:

```
new OpenLocalPDF(context, 'nameOfPDFStoredInAssets').execute()
```

And here is the `OpenLocalPDF` class:

```
public class OpenLocalPDF {

    private static String TAG = OpenLocalPDF.class.getSimpleName();

    private WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference;
    private String fileName;

    public OpenLocalPDF(Context context, String fileName) {
        this.contextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        this.fileName = fileName.endsWith("pdf") ? fileName : fileName + ".pdf";
    }

    public void execute() {

        Context context = contextWeakReference.get();
        if (context != null) {
            new CopyFileAsyncTask().execute();
        }

    }


    private class CopyFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {


        final String appDirectoryName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
        final File fileRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), appDirectoryName);

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Context context = contextWeakReference.get();

            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

            File file = new File(fileRoot, fileName);

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {

                file.mkdirs();

                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }

                file.createNewFile();


                in = assetManager.open(fileName);
                Log.d(TAG, "In");

                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Log.d(TAG, "Out");

                Log.d(TAG, "Copy file");
                copyFile(in, out);

                Log.d(TAG, "Close");
                in.close();

                out.flush();
                out.close();

                return file;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
            super.onPostExecute(file);

            Context context = contextWeakReference.get();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.fromFile(file),
                    "application/pdf");

            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

add this permission in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Not a particularly constructive comment dear @RunLoop. I use this in production so I know that it works in my setup. If you care to elaborate on how it does not work for you, then maybe I would take the time to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

like say [sunsil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244588/sunil), but in the case for external directory.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        copyReadAssets();
    }


    private void copyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        String strDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ File.separator + "Pdfs";
        File fileDir = new File(strDir);
        fileDir.mkdirs();   // crear la ruta si no existe
        File file = new File(fileDir, "example2.pdf");



        try
        {

            in = assetManager.open("example.pdf");  //leer el archivo de assets
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); //crear el archivo


            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + "Pdfs" + "/example2.pdf"), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

change parts of code like these:

```
out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

the before example is for Pdfs, in case of to example .txt

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

**Step 1:** In MainActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity  {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //call this method by passing file name in params.
    readFromAssets("User guide.pdf");
 }

public static void readFromAssets(String fileName) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(fileName);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            out = mContext.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } else {
            out = mContext.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        }
        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    Uri pdfFileURI;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        pdfFileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        pdfFileURI = Uri.parse("file://" + mContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
    }
    intent.setDataAndType(pdfFileURI, "application/pdf");
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
 }

   private static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
     while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
     }
   }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create `provider_paths.xml` inside `res->xml->provider_paths.xml`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <root-path
    name="root"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

**Step 3:** In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial">

  <!-- INSIDE APPLICATION TAG -->

  <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
  </provider>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

No answer worked for me out-of-the-box when attempting to open a file via an intent (in my case PDF) from the assets folder. So here is my solution combining 2 brilliant answers I'm sure it will help someone. Must be for api >= 24.

Once you have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/1133011) and added the your own `GenericFileProvider` and declared it in your manifest within the `Application` tag and created the `provider_paths.xml` simply use the below class and call it like:

`OpenLocalPDF(this, "YOUR_PDF_NAME_IN_ASSETS_FOLDER.pdf").execute()`

***OpenLocalPdf.kt:*** (kudos too the OP https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212708/1133011)

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.AssetManager
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

class OpenLocalPDF(context: Context?, fileName: String?) {
    private val contextWeakReference: WeakReference<Context?>?
    private val fileName: String?
    fun execute() {
        val context: Context = contextWeakReference!!.get()!!
        if (context != null) {
            CopyFileAsyncTask().execute()
        }
    }

    private inner class CopyFileAsyncTask :
        AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, File?>() {
        val appDirectoryName: String? = co.za.umbiflow.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
        val fileRoot: File? = File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
            ), appDirectoryName
        )

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): File? {
            val context: Context = contextWeakReference!!.get()!!
            val assetManager: AssetManager = context.getAssets()
            val file = File(fileRoot, fileName)
            var `in`: InputStream? = null
            var out: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                file.mkdirs()
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete()
                }
                file.createNewFile()
                `in` = assetManager.open(fileName)
                out = FileOutputStream(file)
                copyFile(`in`, out)
                `in`.close()
                out.flush()
                out.close()
                return file
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.message)
            }
            return null
        }

        private fun copyFile(`in`: InputStream, out: OutputStream) {
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var read: Int
            while (`in`.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read)
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(file: File?) {
            super.onPostExecute(file)
            val context: Context = contextWeakReference!!.get()!!

            var pdfUri =
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    context.packageName + ".provider",
                    file!!
                )

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.setDataAndType(
                pdfUri,
                "application/pdf"
            )
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = OpenLocalPDF::class.java.simpleName
    }

    init {
        contextWeakReference = WeakReference(context)
        this.fileName = if (fileName!!.endsWith("pdf")) fileName else "$fileName.pdf"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to open multiple PDF files from assets using a zip file.

> Step1: Copy a zip file(`pdf.zip`) into assets folder that contains the list of pdfs

> Step2: Write PDF's into external cache inside the app in a Utils class

```
public static void writePDFs(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("pdf.zip");
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "PDFs");
            if (!file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
                if (file.mkdir()) {
                    BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                        String s1 = file + "/" + zipEntry.getName();
                        File file1 = new File(s1);
                        if (!file1.exists()) {
                            file1.createNewFile();
                        }
                        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file1));
                        while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                        zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                    }
                }
                zipInputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> Step3: Call the above function in Activities onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FileUtils.writePDFs(this);
}
```

> Step4: Create a common function in Utils class to open the PDF

```
public static void openPDF(Activity activity, String fileName) {
        if (activity == null) return;
        File file = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFs" + "/" + fileName);
        Uri docUri = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), file);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setDataAndType(docUri, "application/pdf");
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
            }
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_VIEW_ATTACHMENT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> Step5: Call the `openPDF` function on click on the view in Activity

```
myView.setOnClickListener(v -> ApplicationUtils.openPDF(this, "MyPdfFile.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had success, using the answer from [cYrixmorten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212708/3742642), with the **OpenLocalPDF** class.

But, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is not supported for Android 18. To support Android 18 - 28, I had to make the following changes.

In "CopyFileAsyncTask", change the fileRoot declaration:

```
final File fileRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), appDirectoryName);
```

To this:

```
final File fileRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourAppName");
```

In "onPostExecute", change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(
        Uri.fromFile(file),
        "application/pdf");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

To this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.yourappname.provider", file), "application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Finally, setup your manifest to support the [FileProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) as described in this post.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public String getAssetsPdfPath(Context context) {
String filePath = context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "myFile.pdf";
File destinationFile = new File(filePath);

try {
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("myFile.pdf");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length = 0;
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error.");
}

return destinationFile.getPath();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open a .pdf file that is stored locally in the assets folder without using an Intent to launch an external app, I suggest using the Android class PdfRenderer. Documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html).

[This](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic) is a good example that worked for me.

However, this example wouldn't run when I downloaded it. I had to change it a bit to use the copyReadAssets() function as mentioned in the other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085759/3703667), then to reference the file (after it has been copied) I use:

```
File file = new File("/data/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/files/mypdf.pdf");
```

I also ended up modifying onAttach() because it was using the deprecated form of onAttach() and closeRenderer() because it was throwing errors for closing objects that were null.

So my complete PdfRendererBasicFragment.java file looks like this:

```
package com.example.android.pdfrendererbasic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * This fragment has a big {@ImageView} that shows PDF pages, and 2 {@link android.widget.Button}s to move between
 * pages. We use a {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} to render PDF pages as {@link android.graphics.Bitmap}s.
 */
public class PdfRendererBasicFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * Key string for saving the state of current page index.
     */
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX = "current_page_index";

    /**
     * File descriptor of the PDF.
     */
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor;

    /**
     * {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} to render the PDF.
     */
    private PdfRenderer mPdfRenderer;

    /**
     * Page that is currently shown on the screen.
     */
    private PdfRenderer.Page mCurrentPage;

    /**
     * {@link android.widget.ImageView} that shows a PDF page as a {@link android.graphics.Bitmap}
     */
    private ImageView mImageView;

    /**
     * {@link android.widget.Button} to move to the previous page.
     */
    private Button mButtonPrevious;

    /**
     * {@link android.widget.Button} to move to the next page.
     */
    private Button mButtonNext;

    public PdfRendererBasicFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdf_renderer_basic, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Retain view references.
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        mButtonPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
        mButtonNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        // Bind events.
        mButtonPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Show the first page by default.
        int index = 0;
        // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
        }
        showPage(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            openRenderer(context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        try {
            closeRenderer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (null != mCurrentPage) {
            outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, mCurrentPage.getIndex());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up a {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} and related resources.
     */
    private void openRenderer(Context context) throws IOException {
        // Copy the pdf to a usable location
        CopyReadAssets();

        File file = new File("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/files/sample.pdf");
        mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
    }

    /**
     * Closes the {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} and related resources.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException When the PDF file cannot be closed.
     */
    private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
        if (mCurrentPage != null) {
            mCurrentPage.close();
        }

        if (mPdfRenderer != null) {
            mPdfRenderer.close();
        }

        if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
            mFileDescriptor.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the specified page of PDF to the screen.
     *
     * @param index The page index.
     */
    private void showPage(int index) {
        if (mPdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }
        // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
        if (null != mCurrentPage) {
            mCurrentPage.close();
        }
        // Use `openPage` to open a specific page in PDF.
        mCurrentPage = mPdfRenderer.openPage(index);
        // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentPage.getWidth(), mCurrentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
        // To render a portion of the page, use the second and third parameter. Pass nulls to get
        // the default result.
        // Pass either RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY or RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT for the last parameter.
        mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        // We are ready to show the Bitmap to user.
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUi();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
     */
    private void updateUi() {
        int index = mCurrentPage.getIndex();
        int pageCount = mPdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        mButtonPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
        mButtonNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name_with_index, index + 1, pageCount));
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of pages in the PDF. This method is marked as public for testing.
     *
     * @return The number of pages.
     */
    public int getPageCount() {
        return mPdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.previous: {
                // Move to the previous page
                showPage(mCurrentPage.getIndex() - 1);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.next: {
                // Move to the next page
                showPage(mCurrentPage.getIndex() + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "sample.pdf");

        if(!file.exists()) {
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("sample.pdf");
                out = getActivity().openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("test", "file already exists");
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code work on every android version:

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import unimedbh.UnimedBH.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE); 

        } else {
            copyReadAssets("YOUR_PDF_NAME.pdf");
        }
    }


    private void copyReadAssets(String fileName) {
        String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = assetManager.open(fileName);
            File outFile = new File(dirPath, fileName);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.package.name.fileprovider", outFile));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.name.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="app_directory" path="directory/"/>
</paths>
```

Tested in API 16-28, worked on all api´s!