# open pdf file from asset folder in android

Tags: android, pdf, resources, assets

I placed a pdf file (bang.pdf) in assets folder, i need to open and display the pdf from assets folder when a button is clicked.
The code is :

```
package com.example.pdfviewer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button but1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);

        but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hai" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CopyReadAssets();

            }
        });
    }
    private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "bang.pdf");
        try
        {
            in = assetManager.open("bang.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/bang.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    }
```

But when i click the button , the following error is displayed
Error : -  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/com.example.pdfviewer/files/bang.pdf typ=application/pdf }
    in mainifestfile:-
    i mentioned 
    
        
        
    I have installed  adobe reader application in my device, still getting the same error message.

please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 1):

file://android_asset only works in your app

You will need to either:

1. Copy the file to external storage, or
2. Copy the file to internal storage and use a ContentProvider to make it available to the  PDF viewing app

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer is given here:

[Read a pdf file from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder)

(it is almost as the question yet additional item is added, the missing request for permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).
file:// seems to be okay and is referring to the external storage.

Maybe there are better ways than to copy outside (copy to internal storage + ContentProvider as suggested by Siddharth Vyas ?).