# How do I get a direct path to the assets folder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-assets

I want a direct path to the assets folder so I can open a PDF that is stored there.
So I can pass it as a parameter in this Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondMainActivity.class);
i.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "path_to_assets_folder");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You post a lot of question but never upvote or mark any answer as correct, this behavior will discourage others to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's because the answers are not working for me

Comment: could you please explain why those answer arent working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/yourfile.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

also you can check this: [Read a pdf file from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder)

Answer (score 0):

from [Android Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets()),

```
public final AssetManager getAssets ()

Added in API level 1
Retrieve underlying AssetManager storage for these resources.
```

so, you can use `getAssets`,

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
```

To access a file in `assets` folder,

```
InputStream is = mngr.open("file name");
```

If your class is not an `Activity`, you'll need to pass a context into it and then call `getAssets` on that.

```
public myClass(Context myContext) {
    AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
    InputStream is = mngr.open("file name");
}
```