# Loading the pdf within the application on Android with PdfRenderer - how to locate the file?

Tags: android, android-file, pdfrenderer

I would like to use [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) to display the `myDoc.pdf` within the application:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/myDoc.pdf");
PdfRenderer renderer 
= new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
...
```

The problem is, I want to include the `myDoc.pdf` in the application rather then assuming it's under `/sdcard/Download/` or on some website.

How can I include the `myDoc.pdf` in the application and **how the path to it should looks like in the code**?

I use Android Studio and I assume the `/res` should be somehow associated with such files.

Comment: you can store the file in assets folder

Comment: please use the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi friend you need to store your pdf file in assets folder.

Please check the stackoverflow question regarding this

[Read a pdf file from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder)

If you still have problem let me know

Comment: Hi. I've added the `myDoc.pdf` under the `assets` folder (that I had to create under `/src/main`). I can access the `myDoc.pdf` from Android Studio and file explorer, but the application cannot load it :/ What do I wrong or what do I miss?

Comment: assets folder is default folder if it is not there right click your project->new-> folder->assets folder and the path you given is wrong try to correct it

Comment: Should it be on the same level as `app`, `build` etc. then? Or inside `app`? Should I also change the `<option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />` from `app.iml`? It has been generated automatically and that's why I assumed it's the place to put my `assets` folder.

Comment: no need to edit any thing in app.iml file just copy paste your file assets folder just like you copy paste images into drawable folder

Comment: No luck so far, I've tried every single subfolder as a parent for my `assets`, including project directory, `src` directory etc. I also upload the needed .pdf file into it (and I see it in Android Studio under my `assets` folder).

Comment: how ur creating folder??

Comment: RMB on project (or any subfolder I want to be a parent) -> new -> directory -> <<folder name>> -> ok. I can see it being created.

Comment: sorry i dont know how much you know about asset manager ,it is finding difficult to clear you you cant create assets folder as sub folder in android app its name path everything is predefined,if you need to access a file you have to provide all correctly.so first try how to create and add a file in asset folder in android

Comment: look this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio