# Show local PDF-File with external app

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I would like to open a local PDF file with a pre-installed PDF-viewer via Share-Intent like this:

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/manual.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

The app-picker is shown, when I click on Adobe PDF it doesn't show the PDF-file however.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: where you have kept the pdf file. is it in assets? The path you are passing is wrong. It is failing to open the file from that path.

Comment: Yes, my file is located in the assets-folder - when I inspected the uri, it looked fine.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder to open a pdf from assets.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/directory/"+theNamesOfFiles)),"application/pdf");   
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Put the file in a public storage where the PDF viewer app can access it
2. Use a `ContentProvider` class to give that PDF viewer access to a private file.

See: 
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html