# Android development: How can i store pdf file in a android app as local file and read that pdf file?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to make a android mobile app which have a `list view` as a `book list` and when i tap on a `list view` cell it's open that book as a `pdf`. I need to store all `pdf` file in my app as local file, as a result user don't need any internet connection for read that books. How it is possible? I am new in android development. Please help me for how can i do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create directory named `assets` in your app and put your `pdf` files in that directory. use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085759/1157879) to read and display pdf files.

Comment: Thanks :)) . Now i understand what should i do.

Comment: @ShuvoKarmakar please accept my answer if that helped you :)