# How to create File object from assets folder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I am trying to read a pdf file from my assets folder but I do not know how to get the path of pdf file.
I right click on pdf file and select "copy Path" and paste it[image]

Here is the another screen shot of my code:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("/Users/zulqarnainmustafa/Desktop/ReadPdfFile/app/src/main/assets/Introduction.pdf");

    if (file.exists()){
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try {
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "File path not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I always get file not found, Help me to create File object or let me know how I can get the exact path for a file I also tried with `file:///android_asset/Introduction.pdf` but no success. I also tried with Image.png but never gets file.exists() success. I am using Mac version of Android studio. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: I am trying to create 'File' where as above one creates InputStream

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder check this, this is similar to what you want to achieve

Answer (score 11):

get input stream from asset and convert it to a file object.

```
File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/Introduction.pdf");
if (!f.exists()) 
try {

  InputStream is = getAssets().open("Introduction.pdf");
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  is.read(buffer);
  is.close();


  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
  fos.write(buffer);
  fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

Answer (score 6):

Short converter (storing asset as cache file) in [Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin):

```
fun fileFromAsset(name: String) : File =
    File("$cacheDir/$name").apply { writeBytes(assets.open(name).readBytes()) }
```

`cacheDir` is just shorthand for `this.getCacheDir()` and should be predefined for you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this code

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("Indroduction.pdf");
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File("new FilePath");
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

   return null;
}
```

Then try with

```
File file = new File("new file path");

if (file.exists())
```