# Read-Only File system android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, filesystems

i'm trying to open a pdf on a button click. No errors pop up in the log but every time i click the button i get "E/tag: Rota.pdf (Read-only file system)" in the run log. i've tried changing the file system using using an adb command and that does nothing. any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read file from assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

Answer (score 0):

May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder) can be helpful to you.

If have a problem with opening PDF file, try below code.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
   startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Cathc exception here
}
```

or

You can try an ACTION_VIEW Intent with a Uri pointing to the file (either on the SD card or MODE_WORLD_READABLE in your app-local file store) and a MIME type of "application/pdf".

or

If you have a problem with Android Studio, [debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) and post useful log here.

Comment: The code seems to be fine. i can click my button but nothing happens the only log message i get is the read only file system one

Comment: @RyanHunter Can you get the path of the file in your log?

Comment: out = new FileOutputStream(file.getName());                        stores the path. used a breakpoint to check this and it's fine

Comment: May be the below link works for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder