# Android read pdf file from asset folder

Tags: android, pdf, assets, android-assets

I try to read a pdf file store in the assets folder. I see this solution :
[Read a pdf file from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder)

But like comments say this it's not working anymore, the file cannot be found, is there another solution for read a pdf file directly, without copy pdf in external storage ? 
And I don't want to use PdfRenderer my minimal API is 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be helpful for somebody so I post my answer :

```
private void openPdf(String pdfName){
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), pdfName);
    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open(pdfName);
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/"+pdfName),
            "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The pdf file is store inside the assets folder