# how to use asset folder to display in gridview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, pdf, assets

i making a gridview to open pdf files from asset
i have used download directory to show pdf file but now i want to use asset
And i am changing main activity and pdf activity to fragments
Guys help me with asset folder

sample code

**CustomAdaptor.java**

```
package com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs) {
        this.c = c;
        this.pdfDocs = pdfDocs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pdfDocs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return pdfDocs.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view==null)
        {
            //INFLATE CUSTOM LAYOUT
            view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,viewGroup,false);
        }

        final PDFDoc pdfDoc= (PDFDoc) this.getItem(i);

        TextView nameTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        ImageView img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdfImage);

        //BIND DATA
        nameTxt.setText(pdfDoc.getName());
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf_icon);

        //VIEW ITEM CLICK
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               openPDFView(pdfDoc.getPath());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    //OPEN PDF VIEW
    private void openPDFView(String path)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(c,PDF_Activity.class);
        i.putExtra("PATH",path);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**PDF_Activity.java**
i will be using fragment instead activity

```
package com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
//import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;

import java.io.File;

public class PDF_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

        //PDFVIEW SHALL DISPLAY OUR PDFS
        PDFView pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        //SCROLLBAR TO ENABLE SCROLLING
//        ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) findViewById(R.id.scrollBar);
//        pdfView.setScrollBar(scrollBar);
        //VERTICAL SCROLLING
//        scrollBar.setHorizontal(false);
        //SACRIFICE MEMORY FOR QUALITY
        //pdfView.useBestQuality(true)

        //UNPACK OUR DATA FROM INTENT
        Intent i=this.getIntent();
        String path=i.getExtras().getString("PATH");

        //GET THE PDF FILE
        File file=new File(path);

            if(file.canRead())
            {
                //LOAD IT

                pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                        Toast.makeText(PDF_Activity.this, String.valueOf(nbPages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).load();

            }


    }
}
```

**PDFDoc.java**

```
package com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf;

import android.net.Uri;

public class PDFDoc {
    String name,path;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**
i will be using fragment instead activity
i need asset folder to show there pdf files

```
package com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final GridView gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,getPDFs()));

            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<PDFDoc> getPDFs()

    {
        ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs=new ArrayList<>();
        //TARGET FOLDER
        File downloadsFolder= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        PDFDoc pdfDoc;

        if(downloadsFolder.exists())
        {
            //GET ALL FILES IN DOWNLOAD FOLDER
            File[] files=downloadsFolder.listFiles();

            //LOOP THRU THOSE FILES GETTING NAME AND URI
            for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
            {
                File file=files[i];

                if(file.getPath().endsWith("pdf"))
                {
                    pdfDoc=new PDFDoc();
                    pdfDoc.setName(file.getName());
                    pdfDoc.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    pdfDocs.add(pdfDoc);
                }

            }
        }

        return pdfDocs;
    }


}
```

**layout**

**activity_main.xml**
i will be using fragment instead activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_pdf.xml**
i will be using fragment instead activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf.PDF_Activity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scrollBar"/>

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.ScrollBar
        android:id="@+id/scrollBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.tutorials.hp.gridviewpdf.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PDF VIEWER" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**model.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pdfImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/pdf_icon"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Check out below link it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it as an input stream like this from a **fragment**

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open(myfile.pdf))
```

You **don't** need permisssions as you're accessing your app's internal files but putting pdf into assets can increase the weight of the app , be careful

and then you can save it as string like that

```
private StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
String mLine;
        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(mLine);
            text.append('\n');
        }
if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        }
```

Comment: yup i am using download manager so user can download according to there choice

Comment: i have question what if i create folder in external so that pdf can be read from there

Comment: download from web? then you should write pdf to the device storage and then access it, so you'll need code to write and read from storage and it's another question

Answer (score 2):

Include this permission in manifest if you are storing pdf in external storage.
    
Use Asset folder like this

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "xyz.pdf");
in = assetManager.open("xyz.pdf");
out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
```

Comment: "xyz.pdf" what if i want display all unknown pdf file present in asset folder

Comment: somehow u should be knowing which pdf has to be displayed. and then u need to pass the pdf name to it.