# Convert Xamarin code to Native

Tags: java, android, xamarin

```
        webView.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode("program.pdf"))));
```

Does someone know the equivalent of that code?

I tried

webView.loadUrl(String.format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", String.format("file:///android_asset/content/{0}",  URLEncoder.encode("program.pdf","utf-8"))));

But i guess it's wrong because it is not doing what it's supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, `String.format` would use `%s` for string values in place of those `{0}` values

Its not really clear what benefits you get from URL encoding `program.pdf` since it's already a valid URL format for a filename, so it's not necessary, but I'll assume that's just an example.

So you're probably looking for

```
String filename = "program.pdf";
String url = String.format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///android_asset/content/%s", URLEncoder.encode(filename ,"utf-8"));
// TODO: print the url here 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Now it doesn't show the missing pdf error but it doesn't show my pdf. I don't know if it is because of this

URLEncoder.encode("program.pdf","utf-8")

Comment: I've not used this PDF.js library before, so I'm not sure how it works. But I would try using some proper native library. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001474/2308683