# Where to store static pdf or general files while building an android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file

I have a number of pdf files (but I might extend the functionality to other document types as well) that I want to show in my app. Static images go in drawable folder, static text goes in the strings file. But where do I put pdf files?

I know I can host it on a server and have a one-time-download kind of thing, but for my app's use case that's impossible. The app is being designed for a very specific use case in mind and I absolutely need to bundle the pdf files along with the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because other answers didn't fully work for me.

Like the other answers, I read the file from assets folder and created a file in internal storage. I used [muPDF](https://mupdf.com/docs/android-sdk.html) which works perfectly with file URI.

`items` is an ArrayList of file names.

```
try
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = assetManager.open(items.get(position));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
    in.read(buffer);
    File targetFile = new File(getFilesDir(), items.get(position));
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    outStream.write(buffer);
    in.close();
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    //Change below intent statements as per your code
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DocumentActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(targetFile));
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create directory named assets in your app and put your pdf files in that directory. use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085759/1157879) to read and display pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can keep your PDF file (or any other file type) inside assets folder. So while downloading the APK form store, it will download those files too. Only problem is it will increase the APP size.

Check the below answer how you can access the PDF file from the Assets using **assetManager**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085759/7023751