# Xamarin forms : Open PDF file in external App

Tags: xamarin.forms, pdf-viewer

I am facing below error when trying to launch a PDF file stored in assets folder of android project in xamarin forms.

**"this file could not be accessed. check your connection or make the filename shorter in xamarin forms"**

Giving shorter file name didn't help.

Below is my code:

```
public interface IDocumentView
    {
        void ShowPDFTXTFromLocal(string filename);
    }
```

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DocumentView))]
namespace Portfolio_Pdf.Droid.Platform
{
    public class DocumentView : IDocumentView
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public void ShowPDFTXTFromLocal(string filename)
        {
            string reportSavedPath = "/data/user/0/com.companyname.portfolio_pdf/files/test.pdf";
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(reportSavedPath);

            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(reportSavedPath));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                var mimetype = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl((string)fileUri).ToLower());
                Android.Net.Uri apkURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
                                 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.ApplicationContext,
                                 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
                intent.SetDataAndType(apkURI, mimetype);
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

                try
                {              
                    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }

            });   
        }
    }
}
```

Android.Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
             android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
             android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
             android:exported="false"
             android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
      </provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
  <external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
  <cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />
  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="." />
  <files-path
      name="files"
      path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: "stored in assets folder" - is it actually an Android Asset?  Or a file you downloaded at runtime?

Comment: I think that if you use [Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#files) in your shared code with a pdf file, it will detect if you have an application to open it, and then do it

Comment: @Jason, It's an Android Asset

Comment: Assets are NOT files - they need to be accessed with AssetManager, not with normal File IO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085574/read-a-pdf-file-from-assets-folder