# AcivityNotFound - viewing pdf in external pdf viewer

Tags: android, pdf, activitynotfoundexception

I am trying to view a local pdf in an external pdf viewer using this code:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://<package-name>/raw/Terms.pdf>");
    try
    {
     Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intentUrl.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
     intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     getActivity().startActivity(intentUrl);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Even though I have Adobe PDF installed, it throws an ActivityNotFoundExcecption.

Why is that?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517412/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-from-res-raw-folder and countless other questions

Comment: @CommonsWare ...none of which worked for me, so I thought I'd ask the question again :)

Answer (score 0):

Few, if any, PDF viewing apps support the `android:resource` scheme. You need to provide your PDF file by some other means to PDF viewers, such as via `FileProvider`, so you can use a scheme (e.g., `content`) that is more likely to be supported.