# Referencing files in Android

Tags: android, file, reference

Why can't I refer to a PDF file in my Android device?

I have a folder named "templates" in the root folder, and I have a PDF file in that. I've tried to refer to the file via the following:

```
File file = new File("/templates/myPDFFile.pdf");
```

but when I try to print `file.exists()`, it always returns me false.

Just as further information, my file hierarchy is:

```
root
  -src
     -com.example.text
        -MyActivity.java
  -templates
     -MyPDFFile.pdf
```

and my code is stored in MyActivity.java.

How do I reference accurately to the PDF file?

Comment: You must put it in assets and get it from there like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder

Comment: Nice reply, it did indeed lead me to the answer I wanted. Thank you, if you'd post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put it in assets and get it from there like : 
[How to open a pdf stored either in res/raw or assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder)