# Issue in opening pdf file from Raw folder

Tags: android, pdf

Hello I am using below code to open .pdf file from **raw** folder which is inside **res** folder.

```
final Intent imageintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
imageintent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myplayback/"+R.raw.demo), "application/pdf");
startActivity(imageintent);
```

It gives me below error :

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.myplayback/2131099648 typ=application/pdf }
```

What should be the issue ? 
Tell me if there any other option available to read pdf file from raw folder NOTE : I have go through solutions provided on stackoverflow but, no success. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    File fileBrochure = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "demo.pdf");
    if (!fileBrochure.exists())
    {
        CopyAssetsbrochure();
    }

    /** PDF reader code */
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "demo.pdf");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try
    {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "NO Pdf Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//method to write the PDFs file to sd card
private void CopyAssetsbrochure() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try
    {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        String fStr = files[i];
        if(fStr.equalsIgnoreCase("demo.pdf"))
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open(files[i]);
                out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + files[i]);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where had you put this pdf file ?

Comment: I have put it inside raw folder.

Comment: @Ankita have you completely read the question ??? :)

Comment: Yes see the answer which i post.

Comment: @Ankita Please, Checkout edit. It gives me File not found or Can't open. I have already given permissions : READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and INTERNET also in manifest..

Comment: post your activity_main2 xml file also

Comment: @Ankita Nothing there, checkout pls. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myplayback.Main2Activity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: @Ankita pls. tell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154503/discussion-between-ankita-and-mashuk-khan).

Comment: pls. share me link..

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154503/discussion-between-ankita-and-mashuk-khan

Answer (score 0):

Please start activity within the try and catch

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View PDF", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If no any application found that time View pdf file using Webview within a App

Comment: its just handling exception. this common thing i know bro.. tell the solution to read the file sucessfully. Error handling i know..:)

Comment: You have to store file from raw to sdcard and after display, follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491210/how-to-open-a-pdf-stored-either-in-res-raw-or-assets-folder

Answer (score 0):

Remove your raw folder and [create asset folder](http://code2care.org/2015/create-assets-folder-in-android-studio/) and then copy your pdf file inside it. [image]

Now it's working fine. Try this.

Comment: Did you got your solution from this?